# phonegap 2.6 iOS Unexpected '@' in program

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

I just created a new phone gap project in Xcode following the step-by-step guide on phone gap and with the default template files it creates I get this error. Does anyone know what this is or how to fix it? It is supposed to be able to build without error the default template project after building but I get this:

Unexpected '@' in program - line 68 CDVNotification.m

```
[self showDialogWithMessage:message title:title buttons:@[buttons] callbackId:callbackId dialogType:DIALOG_TYPE_ALERT];
```

Unexpected '@' in program - line 106 CDVNotification.m

```
NSDictionary* info = @{
            @"buttonIndex":@(buttonIndex + 1),
            @"input1":(value0 ? value0 : [NSNull null])
        };
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste any of your code in?

Comment: I have not copied any of my code into it yet I wanted to make sure it ran before I entered anything.

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have? Those are all part of the new object-literal syntax.

Comment: @mipadi I had 4.3 then upgraded to 4.6 and it is working now. It turns out you need Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 SDK or higher to run the new phone gap 2.6. Add a note about that in the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer version of Xcode. That syntax is part of Objective C's [new literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), so you need a newer version of Xcode/clang to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

If you did any copy/pasting code into your files you could have introduced an invalid character.  Try "re-typing" the lines you have above, then removing the above lines.  Those @ symbols look kind of funny and they should be blue if the compiler accepts them as literals...